# Eclipse CDT debugger does not show console

Tags: eclipse, console, gdb, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug a C program using Eclipse CDT-s debugger and gdb on a Windows7 system, and everything seems fine, except for the console not showing up, which is bad, because my program needs input at some points from the keyboard.
So how should I make Eclipse's debugger work properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your console view open? 
Window->Show View->Console

Comment: Yes, but it shows nothing. And by the way the tutorials I've seen (eg. this one: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/docs/tutorials/debug_tutorial/cdt_w_debug.htm) picture it as a standard windows command prompt window.

Comment: @KaGe: the link you specified doesn't have a windows command prompt window. Does the program launch correctly in non-debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *gdb/mi* or *cygwin gdb* and choose the *Standard Create Process Launcher*, another console window will open when you start debugging.

Even if you use *gdb/mi* and it won't open, please check the gdb command set is set to Standard.
CygWin and Standard(Windows) should not be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not debugging Native? Check in Eclipse Debug Configurations