# Eclipse CDT : running C++ program not showing anything in the console! Why?

Tags: c++, eclipse, console, eclipse-cdt

I'm running the latest version of Eclipse with CDT on Windows 64 bits with Cygwin for compiling the code.

My problem is that when i run any c++ software in eclipse, there is no output in the console.

I have tried this:

[Eclipse CDT debugger does not show console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799080/eclipse-cdt-debugger-does-not-show-console)

and this:

[Eclipse CDT Debug console not displaying program output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888241/eclipse-cdt-debug-console-not-displaying-program-output)

But it does not works.

Comment: What do you believe the program should write to the console and why?

Comment: My program is just a simple Hello World file.  Here it is:   
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "Hello there!" << endl; 
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As guys at ["No Console Output (MinGW, CDT)"](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/) point out, this is probably (or at least sometimes) because Eclipse does not add `PATH` to `MINGW\bin` when launching the executable, so:

In the "Environment" tag, press "New", set it as:

- "Name:PATH"
- "Value:C:\MinGW\bin"

;)

Comment: @Phil Thanks, that's touching (I just had a similair problem and googled through this page to that one...) ;)

Comment: For those who don't know, On Eclipse 3.7.2 and CDT 8.0.2 the preferences for environment variables can be found in Eclipse at:
`Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Environment`

Answer (score 10):

Another solution that works (other than [mlvljr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9897178/1533054)) is by adding the `-static` flag in:

**Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Linker Flags**

Answer (score 3):

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Linker Flags (add -static)

Answer (score 3):

If All above is not working then You can try this

You have to add Environment variable of this project to have the path of MinGW compiler

> Goto Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings, choose the .exe file
>   and press Edit
>       In the Environment tag, press New, and set it as: Name: PATH  Value: C:\MinGW\bin
>
> If you are using cygwin then Value: c:\cygwin\bin

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the console is allocated:

project properties --> Run/Debug Settings --> yours.exe --> edit --> Common --> Check 'Allocate Console'

Comment: Is there any output to the console during the build process?

Comment: Yes.  I have found the problem. I have updated eclipse and now it works :-)  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.  I have found the problem.  It was a bug from Eclipse.

I went in the Help > Check For Updates.

I installed an update and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue not long ago. Follow this [link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) which provides quite a detailed tutorial on how to setup everything. However, the console on Eclipse Mars CDT still did not show anything. After running the generated executable file from the command line i faced the following error:

[image: Apparently some path was missing]

So considering the missing path I searched for it on cygwin main folder and added to the **Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes GNU C++** the path to the missing dll folder: `${CYGWIN_HOME}/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin`. 
Run again the project, and the problem was solved:

[image]

I hope this will help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

As [Singhak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32309457) answered, this issue can be "fixed" on a project-by-project basis by adding a PATH environment variable to the project's Launch configuration: Project > Properties > Run/Debug Settings > (select the project executable) > Edit.. > Environment > New... (Name: PATH, Value: path/to/compiler/bin). But you'll have to do that for every project - I don't think there's a way to set it up to work for every project, at least I have not been able to.

However, if you're running Windows and have MS Visual Studio installed, you can set the project up using Microsoft Visual C++ Toolchains instead of GCC and that should work as expected every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this night be connected to the order in which I installed MinGW and eclipse CDT (Helios). The solution (for me) was to go Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous -> and set Linker flags to -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++. But I seem to need to do this for every project so I'm still searching for a permanent fix.