# C++ Program doesn't show any output?

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying now to execute a C++ program in eclipse, but it doesn't show anything, my code is:

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
    cout<<"i have stucked here, plz do some thing for Me !";
    return 0;
 }
```

I think I am not ok in setting variable path. It is

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung PC Studio 3\;C:\soft\cygwin\bin
```

while my bin path is

```
c:\cygwin\bin
```

Comment: Well, did you correct your environment variable then? Also, are you using pure C++, or the Android NDK?

Comment: Now it gives this in console,                                           make                                                                        make: Nothing to be done for all.

Comment: @Lennart my cygwin install path is c:\cygwin,                             and i have set my path is like                                              %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung PC Studio 3\;C:\cygwin\bin

Comment: @Lennart is my path is ok? please comment so that i could get ride from this problem...

Comment: The cygwin path looks correct now.

Comment: @Lennart Thanks ! Now my program runs successfuly but eclipse  takes too much time to launch my c/C++ program..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
    cout<<"I am stuck here, please do some thing for Me !";
    return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Can't find a source file at "/cygdrive/c/android programs/Demo1/Demo1.cpp" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

Comment: please re-install your IDE. Because, this code is running with the above string output :/

Comment: Now it gives this in console,                                             make                                                                                             make:   Nothing to be done for all.

Answer (score 0):

remove ".h" from header iostream.h because now  .h forms are deprecated from c++ library., 
this is working fine for me..

```
       #include<iostream>
       using namespace std;
       int main()
        {
          cout<<"I am stuck here, please do some thing for Me !";
           return 0;
         }
```

Comment: now i am getting this after your new code:                                
**** Build of configuration Default for project Demo1 ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: i am getting the above string after your new code, so what is going wrong?

Comment: you have given file extension .cpp? and where r u running the code ,in cmd?

Comment: yes i have saved with .cpp and i don't know where this is running i press the run icon above the ide and it shows the console prompt, where i am getting something above code.

Comment: try once in cmd. for this firstly , u have to go to ur dir where u have saved the program (eg. by "cd desktop" command), after for compiling type "g++ -o demo demo.cpp" (demo is ur file name), then for run type : "demo" .. then tell me the result ,because it is working for me

Comment: you only have to type "demo" not "demo.cpp" in cmd for running the program.

Comment: i am only getting this                                                                                                                          
**** Build of configuration Debug for project MyFirstProject in C++ ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: i think there is problem in ur path env variable , add the PATH variable to Run Configuration ,try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099445/eclipse-cdt-running-c-program-show-nothing-in-the-console-why

Comment: yeah i made it correct my enviroment variable is                            variable name :   PATH                                                    variable value :C:\cygwin\bin

Comment: have a look at this also http://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/UsingEclipseCPP/index.html

Comment: it aslo gives an errr :                                                Error: NDK PAATH CAN'T CONTAIN SPACE

Comment: did ur directory name has spaces ,if yes then correct it..alo thoroughlt read this manual ,this wud help u a lot http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm

Comment: if that is not helping either then move MinGW out of the Program Files directory. Make sure its directory contains no spaces! This is the last solution for this problem then.

Comment: ok, thanks for your long conversation, i'll try myself to make it correct, i'll not disturb YOu...