# Write into console while debugging. Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

i cannot to see what i write to the console (Eclipse C++) during debugging

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << i;
    }
```

How to configure Eclipse writting on console while debuging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

related [Eclipse CDT : running C++ program not showing anything in the console! Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099445/eclipse-cdt-running-c-program-show-nothing-in-the-console-why) [Eclipse CDT : running C++ program not showing anything in the console! Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099445/eclipse-cdt-running-c-program-show-nothing-in-the-console-why) [C++ program written in Eclipse using Windows and MinGW cannot display output to console view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959908/c-program-written-in-eclipse-using-windows-and-mingw-cannot-display-output-to) or it might be a bug if you are on win x64: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236330

Answer (score 0):

<sup>It is not Eclispe (which is an editor, not a compiler; probably your Eclipse would run a compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using the `g++` program; and then you are running the compiled executable.).</sup>

If you don't see your expected output, it is probably because your output stays [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

You could try the [std::flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/flush-free/) manipulator.

```
   for (int i=0; i <5; i++)
        std::cout << i << std::flush;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14105650/841108) and the several good answers there.

You might read more about the [std::endl](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) manipulator. I suggest doing `std::cout << std::endl`  from time to time.

You could consider using the [std::clog](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/clog/) output stream.